# How to attach GIOChannel for different context instead of default context?

Tags: sockets, asynchronous

I am writing one simple server and client application which uses socket for communication.
In the client side I have created a **GIOChannel** for listening to socket events such as read, write, exception..etc. Client provides some asynchronous APIs.

I have written one sample application for testing my code which creates **g_main_loop** and creates one GIOChannel for keyboard events.

```
mainloop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);
channel = g_io_channel_unix_new(0);
g_test_io_watch_id = g_io_add_watch(channel, (GIOCondition)(G_IO_IN | G_IO_ERR | G_IO_HUP | G_IO_NVAL), test_thread, NULL);
g_main_loop_run(mainloop);
```

It is working fine if I dont loop or block the main thread in the callback function **test_thread**. For example when I call any asynchronous API of client I put sleep in my sample program for some time and expecting asynchronous message from server by the time main thread wakes up. But this is not happening, client socket getting read event for reading asynchronous message from server only after the main thread which called the API returns.

From this I got to know both keyboad events and socket events registered for same default context and they can not be notified by the main event dispatcher for the same time.

I have to make my program such a way that socket reading at client side should not dependent on the default context of **g_main_loop** so that sync and async both will happen from seperate threads.

I found some APIs through GNome docs which are for adding GIOChannel for only default context. I have to add the GIOChannel created for socket reading to different context.

Can anybody suggest me how to do it or is there any better option available for handling socket reading asynchronously using GLIB.

Thank you.

Comment: Please reply this post if anyone knows the answer...

Comment: Whats wrong with this question...no body is replying..:-(